# React useCallback - Select component rerendering after selecting option - not wanted

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a HTML select drop down list (SortBy component), after selecting an option, the component rerenders, this is not wanted, I want to see the option I selected but it keeps reseting (rerendering) to the first option. I've tried useCallback with no luck

When A-Z or Price: Low to high is selected, I want that value retained in the HTML select box but it defaults back to Relevance

```
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(products);
  console.log(products);

  const onChange = useCallback((e) => {
      const { value } = e.target;
      let arr = items;

      switch (value) {
        case ("relevance", "saleFirst"):
          arr = saleItemsFirst(items, false);
          break;
        case "ascend":
          arr = sortByName(items);
          break;
        case "price":
          arr = sortByPrice(items);
          break;
  
        default:
          arr = saleItemsFirst(items);
          break;
      }

      setItems([...arr]);
    },
    [items]
  );

  const SortBy = useCallback(() => {
    return (
      <select name="filters" onChange={onChange}>
        <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
        <option value="ascend">A-Z</option>
        <option value="priceLow">Price: Low to high</option>
        <option value="saleFirst">Sales items first</option>
      </select>
    );
  }, [onChange]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SortBy />
      <hr />
      <section>
        {items.map((val) => (
          <div>
            <span>{val.productName}</span> <div>${val.price}</div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
      ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**:
`SortBy` is getting re-defined whenever `items` changes because `items` is in *the dependency array* for your useCallback, which tells it when to re-run, re-defining the returned function reference. When that happens, it's a whole new component instance, and it's being remounted with initial values.

`items` *has* to be in your dependency array if you define a function this way, otherwise, when `items` changes, your memoized (useCallback'd) component will be stale.

**The Solution**:
Rather than declaring `SortBy` inside of the App component, you'll need to declare it outside, and pass in any dependencies it needs as props. That way, the SortBy component will be a module-level constant, and it will only mount once when App mounts.

**Takeaway**:
It's generally a bad practice to define components inside of other components. Avoid it. The only possible exception are very simple (like, one-liner) components that have no state concerns. Even then I'd advise defining them outside other components.

Answer (score 1):

I'd echo what [Faust says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76377997/636077) and strongly advise you to move your components out of `App`, but I'd also suggest that you rethink the way you're keeping track of the sort.

Instead of keeping the sorted list items in state you could just keep track of which sort option is selected and memoize the sorted item list, updating it when the selected sort changes:

```js
// we need a list of items to display
const items = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => `Item ${i + 1}`);

// a mapping of sort names to sort functions
const sortOptions = {
  ascending: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b),
  descending: (a, b) => b.localeCompare(a),
  random: () => Math.random() - 0.5,
}

// the component
function MyList () {

  // keep track of which sort name is selected
  const [sortName, setSortName] = React.useState();
  
  // re-sort the item list when the sort name changes
  const sortedItems = React.useMemo(() => {
    // look up the sort function by name and pass it to array.sort()
    return [...items].sort(sortOptions[sortName]);
  }, [sortName]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {/* update the sort name on change, and set the value of the select */}
      <select onChange={(e) => setSortName(e.target.value)} value={sortName}>
      
        {/* render an option for each item in sortOptions */}
        {Object.keys(sortOptions).map(sortName => (
          <option key={sortName}>{sortName}</option>
        ))}
        
      </select>
      
      {/* render the list of items */}
      <ol>
        { sortedItems.map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>) }
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<MyList />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: lol, late response, clever sorting idea, minimal use of state, thanks ray